# How to sort an array based on repeated value angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following data

```
  var data = [
   {
    "h_id"  : "31",
    "city": "hill",       
}, {
    "h_id": "4",
    "city": "Bevery Hills",     
}, {
    "h_id": "5",
    "city": "New York",    
}, {
    "h_id": "31",
    "city": "New York",   
}, {
    "h_id": "5",
    "city": "New York",   
}
];
```

I want data to be sort by "id" order as follow

```
  var data = [
   {
    "h_id"  : "31",
    "city": "hill",       
}, {
    "h_id": "31",
    "city": "Bevery Hills",     
}, {
    "h_id": "4",
    "city": "New York",    
}, {
    "h_id": "5",
    "city": "New York",   
}, {
    "h_id": "5",
    "city": "New York",   
}
];
```

how do i create a function to filter the id value based on above scenerio

Comment: it is neither ascending, nor descending. whats your exact requirement?

Comment: I don't think this is a valid pattern. If you want to sort, the sorting 'h_id' will be like: 31,31,5,5,4 . I doesn't make sense to group in place. You cannot sort in this pattern.

Comment: What should be the output if there are 3 records of `h_id = 5`?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a custom function to JavaScript's [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```js
var data = [{
  "h_id": "31",
  "city": "hill",
}, {
  "h_id": "4",
  "city": "Bevery Hills",
}, {
  "h_id": "5",
  "city": "New York",
}, {
  "h_id": "31",
  "city": "New York",
}, {
  "h_id": "5",
  "city": "New York",
}];

var result = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.h_id.localeCompare(b.h_id);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: no need for `parseInt`, he literally treats those numbers as strings and sorts them alphabetically. E.g. "31" before "4" before "5"

Comment: I think the OP doesn't know what sorting he wants, let alone the sorting by string or integer

Comment: (_you can imagine splitting those numbers per character and treating them as districts_ : `3.1` < `4` < `5`)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey -- thanks for pointing out. Updated the code!

Comment: I want to filter the id like 31,31,4,5,5 not like acednding or decending , i want to filter like if first id is 31 i want all the data in 31 in further object , then next id 4 means i want all data in 4 goes on

Comment: it shows localeCompare is not a function @31piy

Comment: @selvakumar you are using an **outdated browser** then, not every function from ES6 is supported. Check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `.sort` method on your array with a comparator function.

```js
var data = [{
  "h_id": "31",
  "city": "hill",
}, {
  "h_id": "4",
  "city": "Bevery Hills",
}, {
  "h_id": "5",
  "city": "New York",
}, {
  "h_id": "31",
  "city": "New York",
}, {
  "h_id": "5",
  "city": "New York",
}];

var sortedData = data.sort((a,b)=> b.h_id - a.h_id);
console.log(sortedData);
```

Comment: "4" should be before "5"

Comment: This is a wrong answer because you're comparing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array.  Read More about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

And this is the way you can get it done

```js
var data = [
   {
    "h_id"  : "31",
    "city": "hill",       
}, {
    "h_id": "4",
    "city": "Bevery Hills",     
}, {
    "h_id": "5",
    "city": "New York",    
}, {
    "h_id": "31",
    "city": "New York",   
}, {
    "h_id": "5",
    "city": "New York",   
}
];
  data.sort(function (a, b) {
          return parseInt(b.h_id) - parseInt(a.h_id);
     });
     
     console.log(data)
```

Comment: I want to filter the id like 31,31,4,5,5 not like acednding or decending , i want to filter like if first id is 31 i want all the data in 31 in further object , then next id 4 means i want all data in 4 goes on

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort by string (not number) therefore according to [Array sort docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) you should do the following;

```js
var data = [
   {
    "h_id"  : "31",
    "city": "hill",       
}, {
    "h_id": "4",
    "city": "Bevery Hills",     
}, {
    "h_id": "5",
    "city": "New York",    
}, {
    "h_id": "31",
    "city": "New York",   
}, {
    "h_id": "5",
    "city": "New York",   
}
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.h_id < b.h_id) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.h_id > b.h_id) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(data);
```